# wp_query for woocommerce featured product category list is display categories more than once?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, foreach

I've written a wp_query that checks for featured products in woocommerce.

First it gathers all the categories and then it checks if they have featured products. It then displays the category name.
Only issue I have is it duplicates the cat name for each featured product inside it.

Any ideas what I've missed that causes the loop to act this way?
I think my code may be a bit bloated as well.

Thank you

```
<?php
 $fpArgs = array(
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'tax_query' => array(
    'field'    => 'name',
    'terms'    => 'featured',
    'operator' => 'IN',
 )
);

 $featProds = new WP_Query( $fpArgs );

 if ($featProds->have_posts()):
?>

<section class="standard featuredProducts">

 <?php $cat_terms = get_terms('product_cat'); ?>

 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">

  <?php
    foreach ( $cat_terms as $cat_term ):

      $cat_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'title',

        'tax_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( $cat_term->slug ),
            'operator' => 'IN'
          ),
          array(
              'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
              'field'    => 'name',
              'terms'    => 'featured',
              'operator' => 'IN',
          )
        )
      ) );
  ?>

  <?php
    if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) :
      while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) :
        $cat_query->the_post();

      $catName = $cat_term->name;
  ?>

  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" id="cat-tab">
      <?php echo $catName; ?>
    </a>
  </li>

  <?php
      endwhile;
     endif;
   endforeach;
  ?>
</ul>

</section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out a solution...

I added all the categories into an array and used that to select only unique categories with an if statement.

Followed this solution which worked like a charm
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154970/remove-duplicated-values-from-a-loop